# how to parse one news title

Tags: sentence-meaning, headlinese

> *Second-largest school district in the US closes over threat New York officials concluded was a hoax that ‘mirrors recent episodes’ of TV show Homeland.*

I am lost in the syntactic structure of the above sentence. I roughly understand the meaning: the decision to close the school in the US district made by NY officials was based on false information… But I am not able to parse the original sentence. Every time I try to do it it ends that the hoax was Second-largest school district… Is the word "closes" a verb in the sentence?

Comment: I think there's a full stop missing before *New York*.

Comment: @Subjunctive not in this case. relative clause! The "that" has been removed between threat and "New York officials"

Comment: @AlexK Nice, I slipped that.

Comment: Headline ambiguities, haha. I remember this: https://smalltalkbillross.wordpress.com/2011/06/14/clear-communication/

Comment: Also, if you've read the article, it's important to point out that the "Second-largest school district" which closed is actually Los Angeles, and New York City schools did not close because they concluded that the threat (which they also received) was a hoax.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Newspaper headlines, and titles in general, are often not complete, grammatically-correct sentences. Many people have had great fun pointing out clumsy wording and ambiguity in headlines. But this case is far from the worst.

The headline has a series of verbs and nouns, each of which is modified by a phrase acting as an adverb or adjective. As I think through the structure of the headline, I can see how someone could get confused about what phrases are modifying what nouns.

Let's cut it up like this:

The subject of the main clause is "district", specifically, the "second-largest school district in the U.S.". The verb is "closes". So the bare bones of the statement is "district closes".

"Closes" is modified by a lengthy phrase that is acting as an adverb: "over threat" etc.

Nowo let's take that phrase apart. The key word of the phrase is "threat". The district closed because of a threat.

"Threat" is itself modified. What kind of threat? A threat that "U.S. officials concluded was a hoax".

Then "hoax" is modified. What kind of hoax? A hoax that "mirrors recent episodes of TV show homeland".

Answer (score 8):

It is **"news-speak"** for this:

"**The** second-largest school district in the United States **was closed** [*when? today?*] **because of a** threat [*how was it received and from whom?*] **that** New York officials **later** concluded was a hoax that ‘**mirrored** recent episodes’ of **the television show** '*Homeland*.'"

"The hoax," as you already pointed out, was the "threat." And you are also correct about "closes" or (in my translation) "closed" being a verb. Once the headline is written as a complete sentence, no further parsing is necessary.